# WPF Refresh a treeview on mouseleave event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

How can I refresh my TreeView after drag and drop ? 
My drag and drop function works but when 
I tried to refresh doing something like this

```
private void treeView_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        treeView.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

it doesn't work.

Can you help me please ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the layout also. Please, try this

```
    treeView.Items.Refresh();
    treeView.UpdateLayout();
```

Comment: And how do you update the DataContext of the treeview?